# why T does not deduce to int&& here

Tags: c++, templates, rvalue

following is a function template

```
template <class T>
void func(T&& t) {
}

func(4); // 4 is rvalue and T deduces to int
```

so my question is why T does not deduce to int&& ?

I meant that if T deduced to int&&

so that int&& && -> int&& which also makes sense to me!

Comment: How do you know it doesn't deduce to `int&&`? I think it actually does.

Comment: Usage:    int && i = 4; func(i); or func(std::move(i));

Comment: @Rakete1111 I saw the conclusion here http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/perfect-forwarding-and-universal-references-in-c/   search "4 is an rvalue: T deduced to int" to locate that point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> why `T` does not deduce to `int&&` ?

If a template parameter is a reference, the reference is typically dropped before you consider how deduction happens (the exceptions being forwarding references when deduced against lvalues, functions, and arrays).

In this case, `T` is deduced against `4`, which is an `int`, so `T` deduces as `int`. The resulting type, `T&&` is `int&&`.

Note that expressions never have reference type. `4` is an rvalue of type `int`, it is not an `int&&`.

This is consistent with how deduction works generally:

```
template <class T> void foo(T );
template <class T> void bar(T const& );

foo(4); // calls foo<int>, not foo<int&&>
bar(4); // calls bar<int>, not bar<int const&>
```

Comment: Re "T is deduced against 4". Rather, `T&&` is matched with rvalue expression 4. This becomes important in cases where e.g. `const`s are dropped. I don't remember how it's expressed in the standard except that this stuff is awfully and seemingly needlessly complex.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf `T&&` is matched with an rvalue expression of type `int`, which means we drop the reference and just deduce `T` against `int` (which ends up with an argument of type `int&&`). If it was an lvalue of type `int`, we'd deduce `T` against `int&` - the only case where we deduce against a reference type.

Answer (score 7):

Why should it deduce to `int&&`? Notice that the type of the parameter is `T &&`, not `T`. So:

- The desired final type of the parameter (the product of type deduction) is `int &&`.
- The formal form of the parameter is `T &&`.
- What is the simplest `T` such that `T &&` is `int &&`?

Answer: `int`.